# How to install LibreOffice on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, libreoffice, gimp

I have a new tablet, Aquaris M10 with Ubuntu, and I would like to install Libreoffice, can somebody help me?
I also read about The Gimp on Ubuntu Touch, but I don't see both applications on the Ubuntu store.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Touch ships with a utility called [Libertine](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Libertine) that lets you install and run X11-based deb-packaged software without risking the rest of your system.

Some devices, like the Bq Aquaris M10 tablet, ship with a pre-installed Libertine container that offers the GIMP, LibreOffice, Gedit, and a few other applications, available by swiping to the Desktop Apps scope.  For other devices, you need to create a Libertine container using the command line and add packages to it explicitly.

Comment: So, the steps to follow start from the part 'creating a container'? (libertine is already in the image and there is no need to make it writable)

Comment: Correct...  although the M10 already has a container created and pre-loaded with a set of programs, but it's in read-only memory so you can not add more programs to it.

Answer (score 1):

To find out if there is a container:

```
libertine-container-manager list
```

If there is none, create it (in M10 the default container is called `puritine`):

```
libertine-container-manager create --id mycontainer
```

Use `destroy` instead of `create` to clean things up completely.

To install LibreOffice:

```
libertine-container-manager install-package -p libreoffice -i mycontainer
```

It should appear in the "Desktop Apps" scope (this scope is installed through the GUI).

P.S. Some guides mention that the terminal app doesn't have rights to do some things, so enable and configure SSH; then enter the shell through ssh locally before doing anything:

```
ssh localhost
```

P.P.S. I'm using Aquaris E4.5 on OTA-14. It takes almost all available disk space there (or I've accidentally created too many chroots).

Comment: Please don't add the `--type chroot` to the create command since that assumes too much about the underlying container technology which varies from hardware to hardware.  Letting the command choose the right default will do the right thing everywhere.

Also, don't give your conatiner the ID _puritine_ because it will error out on some devices (like the M10) that already have Puritine installed.  Choose a different name.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb, btw change it on your wiki page if it makes sense there (I haven't managed to edit it): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Libertine